# Endless Loop matcher.find()

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to fetch the address from html page. I have a regex and from which I find out the state,city and phone no.

```
String linearray[] = newdoc.split("\n");
int count = 0;
System.out.println(linearray.length);
while(count<linearray.length)
{
    System.out.println(count);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(\\d{1,4}(\\s*\\w*)*)(\\s*)(CA|AZ|NY)(\\s*)(\\(?[1-9]\\d{2}\\)?\\s*\\d{3}\\d{4})?(.*?)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(linearray[count].trim());
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String state = matcher.group(5);
        String city = matcher.group(2);
        String phone = matcher.group(7);
        System.out.println("state "+state+" city "+city+" phone "+phone+" ");
    }
    count++;
}
```

When I try to run this code, it goes into an endless loop.
Can anyone help me in solving this?

EDIT:

When `linearray[count]=="Bombay Garden Newark SanMateo SantaClara &copy; 2011 Bombay Garden All Rights Reserved"`, my code gets stuck on the line `while(matcher.find())`. Any idea why it gets stuck there? when I skip that line(by using continue), the code terminates just fine!

Comment: Are you sure that the endless loop is not in another part of your code? I copy-pasted your code, and it runs fine (and terminates properly) for me.

Comment: yes, its in this part of the code, because I tried to print something right after the end of second while loop and it gets stuck before that and doesnot print anything.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it ?

Comment: What is the goal of the `(.*?)` at the end of your regex? It seems like the `(.*?)` at the beginning would gobble up junk just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Your regular expression leads to "[catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)", making it too complex to be run to completion.

Consider rewriting your regex to be more [possessive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).